# segmentation fault on libusb_get_device_with_vid_pid

Tags: c++, c, linux, libusb

I'm trying to open a connection to a camera from a raspberry pi 2 over usb. I'm able to detect the camera but when I try to open a connection using

```
libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(null, vendor id, product id);
```

But I receive a segmentation fault. I've narrowed it down and that line of code is what causes the segmentation fault.

```
void opendevice(){
    libusb_device_handle* dev;
    struct libusb_device_descriptor* desc;
    int err;

dev = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(NULL,0x2a0b,0x00f8);

   if (dev == NULL){
        printf("device not found\n");
       }

else {
     err = libusb_claim_interface(dev, 0);
     }    
}
```

The message from the pi opened over putty on my computer is.

```
Segmentation fault
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This might be more appropriate for libusb developers. Can you try with latest version of the library, and if it still happens, report a bug to them?

Comment: Perhaps you can debug the program and get a stack trace. You can also use a debug version of the libusb as described in http://www.libusb.org/wiki/debug.

Comment: This still segfaults with the `else`?

Comment: @donjuedo yes it does.

Comment: As you are not showing that part, have you checked your call to `libusb_init(NULL)` ?

Comment: @Leiaz Thanks. I had passed reference to a pointer of null instead of null itself.

Comment: suggest reading the documentation (and code examples) at <http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/148707-introduction-to-using-libusb-10/> which has a number of steps that need to be performed that the posted code is not doing.

Comment: the library is written for C++.   The posted code calls printf() so is for C rather than C++.

Comment: @user3629249 the library is written for c/c++ and it's also available cross platform. This is an excerpt from code the answer has already been found.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `NULL` for `dev`, and using it anyway.  You could add a return statement after the `printf()`, or an `else` before the `libusb_claim_interface()`.

Comment: Heh.. missed it surprisingly..It's like "is there a check? Yes there is." But without paying attention what we do with this check..

Comment: Even if that would be a problem. The problem that returns the segmentation fault is the code that I have specified above. When putting a printf statement before the if statement it is not hit. The problem is within the libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid function or my use of it.

Comment: @MathewWright, Well, I did assume the library call has no internal bug.  The parameters going in are simple, and NULL is permitted as the first param.  So how did you determine the open is where the crash is?

Comment: @MathewWright, Also, it wouldn't hurt to add the return mentioned, retest, and edit the post, just to eliminate distraction (If indeed I'm mistaken).

Comment: @donjuedo, I assumed it would be fine also. I used simple printf statements before and after the open function. The printf after the open function did not show. The program terminates at that function call because of a segmentation error.

Comment: @MathewWright, that is what I suspected.  `printf()` buffers output, so the absence of text is misleading.  That's also why I suggested adding the change anyway.  If the crash is in the claim, and the return is added, the `printf()` output will get a chance to flush.

Comment: @donjuedo I added the change you suggested above to the code above. I have also removed the entire check statement. Sadly I still get the error.